# Curator - How to know current node is leader or not

Tags: java, load-balancing, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Just curious to know whether there is any API to know the a particular node is leader using CuratorFramework class in Curator Framework. I am using LeaderLatch but not working even the Node is leader (Elected by Zookeeper framework).

NOTE: 3 nodes are configured in cluster set up.

Zookeeper framework will take care of electing a node. I need to know the selected Curator client is pointing to leader or not.

```
String zkConnString = "172.18.54.211:2181";

RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3);
CuratorFramework client1 = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkConnString, retryPolicy);
client1.start();

 LeaderLatch leaderLatch = new LeaderLatch(client1, "/FirstNode");
 try {
    leaderLatch.start();

} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("has leader ship ? "+leaderLatch.hasLeadership());
```

The output is

```
has leader ship ? false
```

The Use case is as follows. Micro Services are involved in the use case. 
[image]

If the LEADER corresponding Micro Service went down then need to select another leader. Each Micro service can be treated as a Z-NODE. If a Z-NODE is deleted a NODEREMOVED event will be triggered and listened.

The LEADER should not be Micro Service down node.

Comment: I think most of that already implemented in base zookeper algorithm. Any node can watch other z-node, and once a leader goes down, watcher of that z-node becomes the leader. I'm not clear on what "leader should not be micro service down node", if a node is down leader will be elected if system has the quorum.

Answer (score 2):

I think the state of LeaderLatch(first, second) has changed when the third instance start.

```
leaderLatch.hasLeadership()
```

should be performed after enough instances(3th) started.

or registry a `callback method` when this happend.

implements interface `LeaderLatchListener` and override `isLeader()` or `notLeader()` is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-latch.html), leader election is asyncrhonous. This means that after you have started leader election, leader information is not necessarily available right away.

You should wait for leader election to be completed first.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find clean way of obtaining information about election completion using classes in `org/apache/curator/framework/recipes/leader` package: the API only provides means of checking leadership *change*.

The closest query I'm able to find is this (using Java8):

```
new LeaderSelector(clientFramework, path, new NoOpLeaderSelectorListener())
    .getParticipants().stream()
    .filter(Participant::isLeader)
    .map(Participant::getId)
    .findAny()
    .ifPresent(<... do something with leader node Id ...>);
```

But I am still unclear whether this will yield correct results with more certainty than original variant.

What it will do is:

1. Query current nodes from the Framework using interprocess communication
2. Sort nodes using configured Sorter
3. Mark first node in line after sorting as Leader node for the purposes of that query

there is also a somewhat equivalent query:

```
new LeaderSelector(clientFramework, path, new NoOpLeaderSelectorListener())
  .getLeader()
```

Differences between first and second is if there are no nodes, then dummy participant is object is returned, whereas first query relatively transparently returns `Optional.empty()` if no nodes are there.

Comment: The await () method from docs.. Causes the current thread to wait until this instance acquires leadership unless the thread is interrupted or closed. As per this, I will not be able to come to know the chosen node is leader or not. Actually the 3 instances are configured in cluster.        Edited Question.

Comment: @RamaKrishna.G, agreed, I will remove this answer and do more research into it.

Comment: Really great for going to spend and let me know the answer. Thanks @Prokhorov

Comment: @RamaKrishna.G, well, as far as I can find, the first part of my answer holds, but I wasn't able to find any ways to actually tell if an event is fired when a leader election completes. The notifications only fire when leadership changes, so as far as that framework can tell, a non-leader election participant that wasn't elected will not be able to log it.

Comment: @Prokhorov, Thanks for the comments. I have a basic doubt. The leader election is happening automatically when nodes are set up in Cluster. What does a LeaderLatch will do ? Using this, can I write my leader election algorithms ? Or is it for getting the notifications when a Leader is elected by framework ?

Comment: @RamaKrishna.G, no, I don't think there is a place for custom election mechanism in Curator. You technically can maybe squeeze in your custom sorter for nodes, but that will not be easy for sure. `LeaderLatch` and `LeaderSelector` are places where your node reports that it can be a leader and will get eventually notified about becoming one. There's not much more to that.

Comment: @Prokhorov, I have updated the actual the business use case in the question. Can you please share your ideas how best we can solve ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add listener to LeadLatch by following code:

```
    leaderLatch.addListener(new LeaderLatchListener {
      override def isLeader(): Unit = {
        println(s"I am the lead $i")
      }

      override def notLeader(): Unit = {
        println(s"i am not the leader any more $i")
      }
    })
```